# How to find the the deviance of an as.party object converted from rpart tree in R?

Tags: r, rpart, party

I created a tree in R.

```
rp <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)

## coerce to `constparty'
rp.party <- as.party(rp)
```

Now, I want to find the deviance of the rp.party object. Is there a way to do so without going to the rp object?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not... it shouldn't be a problem to find this by pulling the relevant pieces from the object. Use `str(rp.party)` to look at the structure of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The `constparty` objects in `partykit` currently do not have a `deviance()` method because they don't assume a formal model. The method is completely nonparametric. (The model-based `glmtree()` objects do provide a `deviance()` method.)  However, it might be useful in some cases...I'll discuss with Torsten whether we should add it for `constparty` as well.

In any case, it is not very difficult to set up the binomial deviance for your example "by hand". The `fitted()` method provides the predicted node ID and the observed response. The `predict(..., type = "prob")` method yields the predicted probabilities. With these two pieces of information you can directly compute the deviance as:

```
obs <- fitted(rp.party)[, "(response)"]
pred <- predict(rp.party, type = "prob")
-2 * sum(log(pred[cbind(1:nrow(pred), as.numeric(obs))]))
## [1] 46.90789
```

Or you can re-fit a constant in every terminal node using `glm()` and extract the `deviance()` from that:

```
deviance(glm(`(response)` ~ factor(`(fitted)`),
  data = fitted(rp.party), family = binomial))
## [1] 46.90789
```